# I am getting Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode error

Tags: solidity, metamask, dapps, javascript, evm

I am getting an Invalid Opcode error while calling the refundAmount function which will refund the amount to the customer and cancel his/her ticket bookings. registrations is a structure mapping and the structure includes 3 variables that are in the below manner.

```
struct Registration {

uint8 noOfTickets;
uint amount;
string email;
}
address payable public owner;
uint public ticketsSold;
uint8 public totalTickets;
uint public price;

mapping (address => Registration) public registrations;
```

The below is the refundAmount function. I could have used msg.sender for this but my javascript takes care of it by using the coinbase address.

```
    function refundAmount(address payable _customer)
                      external
                      payable {
    if(registrations[_customer].amount > 0){
        if(address(this).balance >= registrations[_customer].amount) {

            ticketsSold = ticketsSold - registrations[_customer].noOfTickets;
            registrations[_customer].noOfTickets = 0;
            registrations[_customer].email = " ";
            uint refundCustAmount = registrations[_customer].amount;
            registrations[_customer].amount = 0;
            
            _customer.transfer(refundCustAmount);
            
            emit Refund(_customer, refundCustAmount);
    }

}
```

Please help me.
Thank you in advance and Cheers to Ethereum!!

Edit: - This works completely fine on Rinkeby testnet but reverts while using Ganache.

Comment: Is _customer a contract? Where are you testing the contract?

Comment: No customer is the address. Also, I am testing it on truffle ganache.

Comment: Which solidity, ganache, truffle version are you using? It is ganache or geth private testnet? Did you try with a more recent versions? Unless you use recent solidity version with an old ganache it is unlikely it will cause an invalid opcode. If you were using a geth private testnet then it is likely you didn't enable newer opcodes.

Comment: I am using ganache. I have deployed the same using remix and it works for me but after I  deployed it  using truffle, at the time of calling this function throws me this error. The Solidity version that I am using is 0.5.0. Ganache is upto date. I was able to interact with all the functions when I deployed the same using Remix on Ganache using injected web3.

Comment: You can take a look at my github repo if required. 
https://github.com/attalyash/Event-Registration

Comment: I see no obvious mistake. Which ganache version are you using? How is ganache launched? How is ganache configured?

Comment: Ganache version: 2.1.2.0
Config: GAS LIMIT: 6721975
Hard fork: Petersburg

Comment: Latest ganache version is 2.5.4. A possibility is that solc version used generates opcodes for a newer fork than Petersburg. You can either force solc to use Petersburg opcodes, or configure ganache to accept newer opcodes.

Answer (score 0):

would recommend you too to deploy this contract, verify it and add it to tenderly (https://tenderly.co/) and debug the issue.
Secondly would recommend you to use call() instead of transfer it is less costly after the Istanbul fork.

Answer (score 0):

Hitting an invalid opcode typically means you're interacting with an old contract incorrectly, probably calling it with the wrong ABI. For cases were you want to debug this, but don't want to submit verified sources to a third party, you can use the local debugger in [Contract Library](https://library.dedaub.com).